# How do the authors justify that $\mathbb{Z}$, by construction, is clearly minimal?

Tags: proof-explanation, rational-numbers

I am reading Section 9. *The Rational Numbers* from textbook *Analysis I* by *Amann/Escher*, where there is a theorem:

> [image]
>   [image]

My thought:

1. **smallest** means that If there is another domain with unity, $\mathbf{Z}$, such that $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbf{Z}$ and the ring operations on $\mathbf{Z}$ restrict to the usual operations on $\mathbb{N}$, then there is an injective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbf{Z}$.
2. **This ring is unique up to isomorphism** means that If there are two smallest domains with unity, $\mathbf{Z}, \mathbf{Z'}$, such that $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbf{Z}, \mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbf{Z'}$ and the ring operations on $\mathbf{Z}, \mathbf{Z'}$ restrict to the usual operations on $\mathbb{N}$, then $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z'}$ are isomorphic.

My questions:

1. Is my thought correct?
2. I can not justify the statement **Since $\mathbb{Z}$, by construction is clearly minimal** in the proof. Please elaborate more on this point.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I cannot see the two images.

Comment: @zongxiangyi It's strange. I still see them. I try to open this post in Microsoft Edge and still see them.

Comment: the map sending  $1\in \mathbb{N}$ to the unity of such rings. Show that this map is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a smaller ring it would have to contain the additive inverse of $1$ ($-1$ by definition). Then it must contain $-n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, by closedness. In this way one shows that the ring contains all elements of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I got it. Is my above thought correct?

Comment: Yes, but those are just definitions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: When two rings are mentioned, please take care to the notations of the unity of the two rings. So we cannot say "the ring contains all elements of $\mathbb{Z}$" without the clause "up to isomorphism".

Comment: @zongxiangyi Sure, this is really a pedagogical comment.